# Delete rows in CloudBoost using conditions

Tags: cloudboost

Is there a quick way to delete rows in a CloudBoost database without sending an ID as parameter?

For example, imagine that I have a list of **Dogs** and would like to delete those whose **color is white**.

Looking in the documentation, I could create a `CloudQuery` to retrieve all Dogs that matches this condition and then call `CloudObject.deleteAll` to remove all of them. The problem in this solution is that I needed to retrieve all the data to be able to remove them.

Is there any straightforward solution for this problem to avoid making unnecessary requests to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently, cloudboost has no option like this that you are looking for. To delete you have to first fetch cloudobjects then deleteall(). Anyway, you can contact cloudboost team and request for this feature. I am sure they will help you out on this.